# can't not build my app due to an appcompat error

Tags: android

I just got the android studio and all I did was connecting with the firebase. But I was not able to fully connect because of the appcompat error. I have attached the photo of what I'm getting.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs',include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' <--------------getting error here
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        }
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLZ2R.png)

[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXOkC.png)

Comment: This is not error, just warning. You can still continue with your code

Answer (score 1):

I look at your error message and it felt familiar as i had received same message so many times!
Root cause is mixing version numbers in dependencies. it seems that in your dependencies you have version 28 and version 25 mixed up. go to build.gradle and put cursor on version number on each of your dependancies and then press ALT+ENTER. go with what android studio suggests and then clean->rebuild. it should work.
Hope this helps!